# Importing a less file in typescript compiler

Tags: typescript, less

I've got a less file in my code base and I'm using typescript as the language to right the project on top of node. Actually it's a vscode plugin and I was using the following command to compile the typescript to a separate build folder.

`"build": "tsc -p ./",`

which is an npm command. My less files reside in the same path which is given in the above command but unfortunately the less folder is not getting copied to the build folder. My `tsconfig` looks like as following.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "lib",
      "module": "esnext",
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es6", "dom","es2017"],
      "sourceMap": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "rootDirs": ["src"],
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "lib"
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I googled and got the answer of using the `copy-files` node module to manually copy the files but would like to know the possibility of doing it through the `typescript` compiler.

Comment: This is not possible with typescript because tsc is a compiler, not a bundler. You might try `webpack` or simply running `cp` to copy the files where you need them to go.